# A blank page is show instead of error page for exception in JSP

Tags: jsp

I need to setup a general error page for my jsp program, I test it by making a general error page, then having  `<%@ page language="java" errorPage="error.jsp" %>`  at the first line of a jsp page, then create an exception in the page, but just a blank page is show instead of forward to general error page. I guess there is some setting problem? Thanks for your help.

Comment: add `<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %> ` in `error.jsp` where you can get implicit object `exception` to print the exception

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have something like this in your web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/errorpage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Or for instance in case of 404

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code> 
    <location>/errorpage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Try adding the isErrorPage attribute within the page directive on top of your errorpage.jsp and set it to "true"

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 " isErrorPage="true" %>
```